# update a List with structs Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an an object as

```
%{
  shares: []
}
```

I want to add a struct `%Cs{name: "Junaid1"}`, `%Cs{name: "Junaid2"}` into the list through `Enum.each` or `map`, is that possible to do?

Okay for just more brief I am updating question again..

```
 Enum.each(email_array, fn (email) ->
    with {:found_user, sharee} <- ensure_user(email)
    do
      case CameraShare.create_share(camera, sharee, caller, params["rights"], params["message"]) do
        {:ok, camera_share} ->
           #Add camera_share to list
        {:error, changeset} ->
          #Add error to a list
      end
    else
      {:not_found, email} ->
        case CameraShareRequest.create_share_request(camera, email, caller, params["rights"], params["message"]) do
          {:ok, camera_share_request} ->
            #Add camera_share to list
          {:error, changeset} ->
            #Add error to list
        end
    end
  end)
```

and then at the end of Enum.each.. there will be a map as

```
%{
   shares: [all shares],
   errors: [all errors]
}
```

where as each share is of type `%CameraShare{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "camera_shares">}`

Comment: What have you tried so far and what's the result you're currently getting?

Comment: Okay thanks. I have updated it again.. in very easy possible way, where you can understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map = %{
  shares: [%{name: "Junaid0"}]
}
add_shares = [%{name: "Junaid1"}, %{name: "Junaid2"}]
```

#### Straigt list concatenation

```
%{map | shares: map[:shares] ++ add_shares}
```

#### Comprehension

```
%{map | shares: (for share <- add_shares, into: map[:shares], do: share)}
```

#### `Enum.reduce`

```
Enum.reduce(add_shares, map, fn share, acc ->
  %{acc | shares: [share | acc[:shares]]}
end)
```

#### `Enum.into`

```
%{map | shares: Enum.into(add_shares, map[:shares], & &1)}
```

---

**FWIW:**

Adding an element to already existing list:

```
list = []
element = 42

list1 = [element | list]
#⇒ [42]
list2 = [element | list1]
#⇒ [42, 42]
```

---

Answer to updated question (simplified):

```
Enum.reduce(email_array, {[], []}, fn
  email, {shares, changes} = _acc ->
    with {:found_user, sharee} <- ensure_user(email) do
      case :camera_share do
        {:ok, camera_share} ->
           {[camera_share | shares], changes}
        {:error, changeset} ->
           {shares, [changeset | changes]}
      end
    else
      # basically the same
      # make sure ALL branches return an acumulator
    end
  end)
```

The above would return a tuple `{shares, changes}` that you might assign to anything.

Comment: Actually, the question is starting from that point. `[%{name: "Junaid1"}, %{name: "Junaid2"}]` How can all these values first can be in a list? as after one operation,, user is getting one `%{name: "Junaid1"}`, question is how to save all of these in a list

Comment: `add_shares = [%{name: "Junaid1"}, %{name: "Junaid2"}]` the goal is to achieve this state.. how to hold these values together in an Enum.each or map

Comment: Thanks for your answer really appreciate it. But I have updated it.. a little bit more explanation that What I am trying to achieve.

Comment: This is the actually place where I am stuck at the moment `[%{name: "Junaid1"}, %{name: "Junaid2"}]` how to make that

Comment: as you see everything is in an each loop, where I want together all camera shares and errors together

Comment: Is it possible? that on `{:ok, camera_share}` I may add this share to a list.. and on the next iteration,, I have old camera_share added and add new one to update the list?

Comment: With `Enum.each` you can not update anything, because **_everything is immutable_**. You have to return (and probably rebind) the result.

Comment: Use [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) and return an updated accumulator on each step. You have to get that **one can not mutate objects in Elixir** in the first place.

Comment: I am sorry for bothering again and again but can you elaborate little bit in the answer how I can hold that list? with Reducer or map?

Comment: As I am going to have 2 reducers one for camera share and one for errors.

Comment: Updated an answer. One single reducer for both is fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mudasobwa.. Can you point me to learn these things? what should I use or read? for it?

Comment: Save for a great [official documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/learning.html) I have no idea. I never read tutorials, I feel it easier to code myself and examine [Elixir source code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/tree/master/lib/elixir/lib) that is an outstanding source of the inspiration.

Comment: Btw.. I assigned this to a variable all_shares, everything runs right. But all_shares is giving only `:ok`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148576/discussion-between-mudasobwa-and-junaid-farooq).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple method like this:

```
def add_share(%{shares: shares} = map, share) do
  %{ map | shares: [share | shares] }
end
```

And call it to add items to the lists in the map:

```
%{shares: []}
|> add_share(%Cs{name: "Junaid1"})
|> add_share(%Cs{name: "Junaid2"})
```

Result:

```
%{shares: [%Cs{name: "Junaid2"}, %Cs{name: "Junaid1"}]}
```